# How to avoid infinite loop in when call a function to change state in useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

On a sub component I have a function that updates a local state based on some conditions. I want to call the function when data changes, but it result in an infinite loop following the useEffect guidelines.

```
const func(val:any,arr:any[]){
  ...
  setArr(arr)
}

useEffect(() => {
  val && val.length > 0 && func(val,arr)
},[val,func,arr])
```

Comment: Remove `arr` in `[val,func,arr]`

Comment: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'arr'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps 

Answer (score 0):

```
const func(val:any,arr:any[]){
  ...
  setArr(arr)
}

useEffect(() => {
  val && val.length > 0 && func(val,arr)
},[val])
```

I'm hoping val is a variable inside the component function this renders if and only if val changes you have to pass variable which you want useEffect to look out for and make changes based on that change.

adding a function in an array dependency will always lead to an infinite loop because array dependencies watch for changes and render components based on those changes

useEffect: hey function I was told to call you.

Function: hey useEffect I hear you.

useEffect: hey function you answered bro I have to call you again since you're in my dependency.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the useEffect as in your example and everything work except that React keep sending warnings. Val is a local state based on a prop value.

Comment: Scope in JavaScript refers to the current context of code, which determines the accessibility of variables to JavaScript. The two types of scope are local and global, Global variables are those declared outside of a block, Local variables are those declared inside of a block . For example, a function is a block of code any code outside that function can't access any variable inside that function.